# Laravel separate backend and frontend

Tags: laravel, rest, laravel-5

while building with Laravel probably you may have faced the same situation where you have a RESTful service with JSON replies and, at the same time, you need to have a frontend able to consume those APIs to offer a web interface.

Now, the most obvious solution would be to use Laravel Blade template engine and to diversify routes according to the address (*/resource* or */api/resource*). 
However, this approach brings in an additional burden, directly reflected in controllers, where are you have to consider not only the reply itself but also whether it comes from a device or from the web interface and reply accordingly.

I have also seen a lot of frontends actually detached from the backend and built using serverless technologies such as Angular or React, so that both the web interface and the mobile app consume the same APIs and the backend can be much simplified.

Let's take as an example a "Uber for..." service consisting of a native app, a PWA and an admin interface (web), which approach would be the most advisable and why?

Comment: I personally like to keep my frontend detached from backend. But i faced some problems related to SEO for my SPA written in react.   Here's the link of my base setup with laravel : https://github.com/Vishal0203/react-redux-laravel-soup

Comment: The new versions of Laravel (>5) support quite well the api/web separation, with errors being displayed in JSON or HTML according to the headers sent. Nonetheless I still see that programming both backend and frontend on the same repository and the same framework cause a lot of misunderstandings and unnecessary complexity. But SEO for a REST server?

Comment: SEO will be for the frontend, and since single page application will have only one page returned from the backend, you can't really optimise all of the pages description, keywords etc. based on page content. Leading to limited SEO. I think there is more research to be done.

Comment: My current setup is to have separate pages with Blade and controllers retrieve either the resource (eg. return User::find($id)) or a JSON representation depending on the request type. But controllers are a mess